# Problem in "proof" that nonempty perfect set without rationals cannot exist.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, fake-proofs

**Q:** *(Baby Rudin Chap $2$ Prob $18$) Is there a nonempty perfect set in $\mathbb R$ which contains no rational number?*

**Proof (which is obviously wrong since there are counterexamples):**

Consider that such a set exists. It follows that it must have a irrational point. By the definition of perfect set, this point must be a limit point. By definition of limit point, we get that a rational number must be part of this set (since there is a rational between any two numbers). This contradicts the property of the set. Hence, no such set can exist.

**What is wrong with this "proof"? I must be missing some basic definition.**

Comment: That is not how limit points are defined.

Comment: $x$ is a limit point of $S$ if every nhood of $x$ contains an element of $S$ distinct from $x$.

Comment: Which is the rational number in $\{\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

> By definition of limit point, we get that a rational number must be part of this set (since there is a rational between any two numbers).

If $x$ is a limit point of $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ then there must be a sequence $(y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of points in $A$ with limit $x$ ... but all those points could be irrational! That is, we could "skip over" each rational.

It might help to consider the picture with "rational" and "irrational" switched: there are irrationals between any two numbers, but $$0,{1\over 2}, {3\over 4}, {5\over 6}, ...$$ is a sequence containing no irrationals which converges to the rational $1$. It's an easy exercise to "flip this around" and get a sequence of irrationals converging to an irrational.

Comment: (+1) Thanks, in hindsight, this was an obvious mistake, but I am currently struggling with the barrage of definitions that this chapter is. Hopefully this gets better with practise:)

Comment: @Agile_Eagle It does, albeit sometimes slowly.